# Blender 2.77 glitching whenever it processes

Tags: versions

Please help this rookie! .I just installed blender v2.77 and it significantly faster than the previous one when i'm working on the same file. However blender glitches everytime it calculating something, and everything is fine when everything is settled, and the glitch is quite annoying as seen bellow, how do I fix this:
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should test you VRAM. You'll find infos and tools [here](http://superuser.com/q/456435/599208) and [here](http://superuser.com/q/133844/599208)

Comment: That does look like an issue with the video card. Try reinstalling/updating the drivers for it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions, when I turned off services and startups everything work fine except that blender got slow again like usual, this glitch is actually a consequence of an improvement (hopefully)! still have no explaination of the cause though, but wouldnt mind a bit of visual annoyance for a lot of speed =)))